# I want to have a JPanel with both a Java 2d Graphics Section and a JComponent Section at the bottom

Tags: swing, java-2d

This is for a tower defense game and i want the top section to be the map and objects drawn in 300x200 panel and the bottom be a 300x100 panel with multiple JButtons and JLabels. How would I do this. I have used swing for a long time I just don't know exactly how to separate the Graphics part from the other components.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest putting 2 JPanels inside your main JPanel. The top one would be for the map and objects, and the bottom one would contain your JButtons and JLabels. 
Just remember to set an appropriate LayoutManager for the main JPanel.

Comment: What layout manager would you suggest using for the main JPanel

Comment: I would use a border layout, or a vertical box layout. you just have to make sure that your game JPanel's size is set so it doesn't get squashed. Here's some very useful info about layout managers http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html